# How to create a index for a slider?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create a image slider which contains an **image**, **slogan** and **link**. It should be super lightweight and although mobile friendly.

Thats my current markup:

```
<div id="slider">

    <ul id="slider_images" class="clearfix">
        <li id="sl1" class="active">Image 1</li>
        <li id="sl2">Image 2</li>
        <li id="sl3">Image 3</li>
        <li id="sl4">Image 4</li>
    </ul><!--#slider_images-->

    <ul id="slider_text" class="clearfix">
        <li id="st1" class="active">Slogan 1</li>
        <li id="st2">Slogan 2</li>
        <li id="st3">Slogan 3</li>
        <li id="st4">Slogan 4</li>
    </ul><!--#slider_text-->

    <ul id="slider_select" class="clearfix">
        <li class="active">Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
        <li>Link 3</li>
        <li>Link 4</li>
    </ul><!--#slider_select-->

</div>
```

How can I "bind" `Image 1` to `Slogan 1` and `Link 1`, and as well `Image 2` to `Slogan 2` and `Link 2`, so that I am able to target the "groups" as selector with `addClass('active')` and `removeClass('active')`?

For example

```
 $group_1.addClass('active')
```

should target "Image 1", "Slogan 1", and "Link 1".

[**Minimized example on jsfiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/xgnLavp6/3/)

Comment: you want a generic code for binding hover event?

Comment: Sorry, no idea from the question what you want help with.

Comment: to be honest I do not understand your comment (generic code). I want to loop the class `active`, until someone hovers the `#slider`. Then I assign the class `active` by hovering a `li`

Comment: @freedomn-m I have updated my question, I hope it is now easier to understand.

Comment: Makes more sense now and relevant answers are coming in:  As I understand the (updated) question:  When changing slider_select active also change slider_text + slider_images active (eg, but not limited to, user points at link1 and both image1 and slogan1 have class `active` applied).

Comment: Yes exactly thats the way it is supposed to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my other answer, I've decided to make a new one with an actual working image slider thingy! Yay

Here you go:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    var sliderSpeed = 3000 //Milliseconds
    
    // Cache Elements
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var $slider_images = $('#slider_images li');
    var $slider_text = $('#slider_text li');
    var $slider_select = $('#slider_select li');

    $slider_images.not('.active').css({
        "opacity": 0
    });
    $slider_text.not('.active').hide();

    $slider_select.mouseenter(function () {
        var index = $(this).index();
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            change(index);
        }
    });

    var slider = setInterval(function () {
        getProperIndex($slider_select.index($slider_select.closest('.active')));
    }, sliderSpeed);

    function getProperIndex(index) {
        if (($slider_select.length - 1) == index) {
            index = 0;
        } else {
            index++;
        }

        change(index);
    }

    function change(index) {
        clearInterval(slider);
        slider = setInterval(function () {
            getProperIndex($slider_select.index($slider_select.closest('.active')));
        }, sliderSpeed);

        $slider_select.removeClass('active');
        $slider_images.removeClass('active').stop(false, false).animate({
            "opacity": 0
        });
        $slider_text.removeClass('active').stop(false, false).slideUp("fast");
        $slider_select.eq(index).addClass('active');
        $slider_images.eq(index).addClass('active').stop(false, false).animate({
            "opacity": 1
        });
        $slider_text.eq(index).addClass('active').stop(false, false).slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

```css
body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#slider {
    background-color:black;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:1.2em;
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
    overflow:hidden;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
}
#slider_text li {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color:white;
    padding:0.5em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#slider_select {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -6px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -6px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px -6px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#slider_select li {
    display:table-cell;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color:#aaa;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0.5em;
}
#slider_select li.active {
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper clearfix" id="slider">
    <ul id="slider_images" class="clearfix">
        <li id="sl1" class="active">
            <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Gitara_elektryczna1.jpg' />
        </li>
        <li id="sl2">
            <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/Crystal_coop_city.png' />
        </li>
        <li id="sl3">
            <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Danaus_genutia_06847.JPG/1920px-Danaus_genutia_06847.JPG' />
        </li>
        <li id="sl4">
            <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Ahaetulla_prasina%2C_oriental_whipsnake_-_Kaeng_Krachan_National_Park.jpg/1920px-Ahaetulla_prasina%2C_oriental_whipsnake_-_Kaeng_Krachan_National_Park.jpg' />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!--#slider_images-->
    <ul id="slider_text" class="clearfix">
        <li id="st1" class="active">Slogan 1</li>
        <li id="st2">Slogan 2</li>
        <li id="st3">Slogan 3</li>
        <li id="st4">Slogan 4</li>
    </ul>
    <!--#slider_text-->
    <ul id="slider_select" class="clearfix">
        <li class="active">Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
        <li>Link 3</li>
        <li>Link 4</li>
    </ul>
    <!--#slider_select-->
</div>
```

The image slider is currently set to `100vh` and `100vw` for `height` and `width` respectively. You can change this to whatever values you want to change the size of the image slider.

Here's a jsfiddle too! http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/p6jv9a2e/

---

**EDIT**
As per your comment, mouseleave now restarts the interval instead of the mouseenter event. The mouseenter event now stops the interval.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    var sliderSpeed = 3000 //Milliseconds
    
    // Cache Elements
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var $slider_images = $('#slider_images li');
    var $slider_text = $('#slider_text li');
    var $slider_select = $('#slider_select li');

    $slider_images.not('.active').css({
        "opacity": 0
    });
    $slider_text.not('.active').hide();

    $slider_select.mouseenter(function () {
        var index = $(this).index();
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            change(index);
        }
    });
    
    $slider_select.mouseleave(function () {
        slider = setInterval(function () {
            getProperIndex($slider_select.index($slider_select.closest('.active')));
        }, sliderSpeed);
    });

    var slider = setInterval(function () {
        getProperIndex($slider_select.index($slider_select.closest('.active')));
    }, sliderSpeed);

    function getProperIndex(index) {
        if (($slider_select.length - 1) == index) {
            index = 0;
        } else {
            index++;
        }

        change(index);
    }

    function change(index) {
        clearInterval(slider);

        $slider_select.removeClass('active');
        $slider_images.removeClass('active').stop(false, false).animate({
            "opacity": 0
        });
        $slider_text.removeClass('active').stop(false, false).slideUp("fast");
        $slider_select.eq(index).addClass('active');
        $slider_images.eq(index).addClass('active').stop(false, false).animate({
            "opacity": 1
        });
        $slider_text.eq(index).addClass('active').stop(false, false).slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

```css
body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#slider {
    background-color:black;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:1.2em;
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
    overflow:hidden;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
}
#slider_text li {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color:white;
    padding:0.5em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#slider_select {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -6px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -6px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px -6px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#slider_select li {
    display:table-cell;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color:#aaa;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0.5em;
}
#slider_select li.active {
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper clearfix" id="slider">
    <ul id="slider_images" class="clearfix">
        <li id="sl1" class="active">
            <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Gitara_elektryczna1.jpg' />
        </li>
        <li id="sl2">
            <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/Crystal_coop_city.png' />
        </li>
        <li id="sl3">
            <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Danaus_genutia_06847.JPG/1920px-Danaus_genutia_06847.JPG' />
        </li>
        <li id="sl4">
            <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Ahaetulla_prasina%2C_oriental_whipsnake_-_Kaeng_Krachan_National_Park.jpg/1920px-Ahaetulla_prasina%2C_oriental_whipsnake_-_Kaeng_Krachan_National_Park.jpg' />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!--#slider_images-->
    <ul id="slider_text" class="clearfix">
        <li id="st1" class="active">Slogan 1</li>
        <li id="st2">Slogan 2</li>
        <li id="st3">Slogan 3</li>
        <li id="st4">Slogan 4</li>
    </ul>
    <!--#slider_text-->
    <ul id="slider_select" class="clearfix">
        <li class="active">Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
        <li>Link 3</li>
        <li>Link 4</li>
    </ul>
    <!--#slider_select-->
</div>
```

And the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/p6jv9a2e/1/

Comment: this is brilliant and absolutely adds function I need (like the automatic loop!)
If you would like to improve it in case of usability you should stop the loop while someone is hovering `#slider_select`!

Comment: I reset the loop when the user hovers an item, but yes that functionality could be implemented, and quite easily too

Comment: I've now edited my answer and created a new snippet and fiddle accordingly, and added them to my post

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Cache Elements
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var $slider_images = $('#slider_images li');
    var $slider_text = $('#slider_text li');
    var $slider_select = $('#slider_select li');

     $slider_select.hover(function () {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $slider_select.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $slider_images.removeClass('active');
        $slider_text.removeClass('active');
        $slider_images.eq(index).addClass('active');
        $slider_text.eq(index).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 1.2em;
}
#slider_select li {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.active {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper clearfix" id="slider">
    <ul id="slider_images" class="clearfix">
        <li id="sl1" class="active">Image 1</li>
        <li id="sl2">Image 2</li>
        <li id="sl3">Image 3</li>
        <li id="sl4">Image 4</li>
    </ul>
    <!--#slider_images-->
    <ul id="slider_text" class="clearfix">
        <li id="st1" class="active">Slogan 1</li>
        <li id="st2">Slogan 2</li>
        <li id="st3">Slogan 3</li>
        <li id="st4">Slogan 4</li>
    </ul>
    <!--#slider_text-->
    <ul id="slider_select" class="clearfix">
        <li class="active">Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 1</li>
    </ul>
    <!--#slider_select-->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I understand the use of `index` much better now!
Does the repeated use of `find(li)` slow down the script?

Comment: There, Bellash edited my answer to not use `find()`. P.S. Thanks Bellash

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to group them, you can grab them all based upon their parent container and therefore use a very small amount of JS:

```js
$('#slider_select li').on('mouseover', function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  $('ul li').removeClass('active');
  $('ul').each(function() {
    $(this).children('li').eq(index).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  display: none;
}
li.active {
  display: block;
}
#slider_select li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#slider_select li.active {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">

  <ul id="slider_images" class="clearfix">
    <li id="sl1" class="active">Image 1</li>
    <li id="sl2">Image 2</li>
    <li id="sl3">Image 3</li>
    <li id="sl4">Image 4</li>
  </ul>
  <!--#slider_images-->

  <ul id="slider_text" class="clearfix">
    <li id="st1" class="active">Slogan 1</li>
    <li id="st2">Slogan 2</li>
    <li id="st3">Slogan 3</li>
    <li id="st4">Slogan 4</li>
  </ul>
  <!--#slider_text-->

  <ul id="slider_select" class="clearfix">
    <li class="active">Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
    <li>Link 4</li>
  </ul>
  <!--#slider_select-->

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ngoaovvr/4/

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! But I do not want to use a separate navigation, the "Link 1" "Link 2" should be the "selectors" that activate the script by using a `hover` action! I will try to adopt this script and change it to my needs, thanks!

Comment: @MarianRick That's easily fixed http://jsfiddle.net/ngoaovvr/4/. Updated answer too.

Comment: I have tried to use cached selectors, which broke the script. I cannot find my error. Can you help me out? http://jsfiddle.net/ngoaovvr/5/

Comment: @MarianRick You didn't need to use any `find` calls: http://jsfiddle.net/ngoaovvr/6/. Also, if you know you're only going one level deep (e.g. UL > LI), use `children` instead of `find`

Answer (score 1):

I honestly didn't test this, but I think it gives you the right direction for a short block of code.

```
function mySlideShow() {
    $("#slider").on("hover", "#slider_select li", function () {
        var that = this;
        $("#slider").find("li").removeClass("active")
        $("#slider ul").each(function () {
            $(this).children().eq($(that).index('li')).addClass("active");
        })
    })
}
```